# Catch opened word file event

Tags: events, file-io, ms-word

I want to make an application as a word add-in that changes files when they are opened.

So I created a word add-in project in visual Studio, and this is basically the code I have :

```
namespace WordAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
     private void Application_DocumentOpen(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("doc opened");
    // do my stuff
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Application.DocumentOpen += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentOpenEventHandler(Application_DocumentOpen);
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

The problem is, this works well if you start an empty word application (double click word.exe), then open a document, but not if the word application is started together with the document opening (double click a .doc file).

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentOpen won't fire if you open Word by double-clicking on a document.

To Work around this you can check if a document was opened in Word and if so pass the document to Application_DocumentOpen method.

BTW - You seem to have changed the code in the InternalStartup method. As indicated by the comments you should not do this, but instead uses the ThisAddIn_Startup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code to do what Abbey suggested:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs a)
{
  try
  {
    Word.Document doc = this.Application.ActiveDocument;
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(doc.Path))
    {
      logger.Debug(String.Format("Word initialized with new document: {0}.", doc.FullName));
      ProcessNewDocument(doc);
    }
    else
    {
      logger.Debug(String.Format("Word initialized with existing document: {0}.", doc.FullName));
      ProcessOpenedDocument(doc);
    }
  }
  catch (COMException e)
  {
    logger.Debug("No document loaded with word.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You often will have the `DocumentOpen` event triggered before your AddIn is loaded and sometime before the document is actually loaded into the Word Interop API. This means that on `ThisAddIn_Startup`, `WordApp.ActiveDocument` still returns `Null`.

A trick is to schedule a Task (`System.Func<Boolean>`) in your `ThisAddIn_Startup` event: I use a `Windows.Forms.Timer` and that works quite well. On `Timer.Tick`, try to execute the Task. If it returns false, then try again 500ms later, and so on until it works.

My Task is:

```
If WordApp.ActiveDocument Is Nothing Then Return False
DoSomething()
Return True
```

The timer will keep trying until you have an active document, i.e. until you can do something with the document the user opened by double-click.

There are other ways to expose this same mechanism: you could for example wrap this into a `WordStartup` object that exposes a `DocumentOpenBeforeAddInStartUp` event and listen to this. You could also have a wrapper of all Document changes events and trigger your own `DocumentChange` event when either `WordStartup.DocumentOpenBeforeAddInStartUp`, `WordApp.DocumentChange`, `WordApp.DocumentOpen` or  `WordApp.NewDocument` triggers.